# Proving that the Set of Outputs of a Function f(n) over Natural Numbers Has a Power of 2

Tags: number-theory, functions, pigeonhole-principle

I have a function f(n) defined over the set of natural numbers, where each input n corresponds to a unique output f(n), ensuring that the function's values are distinct. I am trying to prove that the set of outputs of this function must contain a power of 2 somewhere.

Intuitively, it seems plausible, as the set of natural numbers is infinite, and if each output is unique, there should be a point where the number of distinct outputs reaches a power of 2. However, I am struggling to formalize this proof.

I've considered strategies involving pigeonhole principle or possibly using properties of powers of 2, but haven't made significant progress. Could someone provide insights or a proof sketch to help me tackle this problem? Any assistance or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Am I misunderstanding your question? Since powers of two are pretty sparse, it's not hard for a function to avoid them. For example, $f(n) = 2n + 3$, $f(n) = 3^{n + 1}$, or simply the function whose outputs are $3, 5, 6, 7, 9, ...$.

Comment: You're not misunderstanding the question, but I might not have been clear enough. I'm referring to cases like the Collatz conjecture or functions with similarly unpredictable outputs, where the distribution of outputs isn't easily discernible or controlled. In such scenarios, if I can prove for eg that no value is repeated, despite the sparsity of powers of two, I think there's a deeper pattern or structure at play that ensures the presence of a power of 2 within the set of outputs.

Comment: What is given about $f$, other than injectivity? Also, what is the source (Did you make it on your own?)

Comment: You can't prove it, because it's false. Let, for (counter)example, $f(n)=7+2n$ – each value is distinct and they are all odd, so certainly _none_ of them is a power of $2$.